# Booting Windows from HDD when BIOSs doesn't recognize it

Tags: boot, bios, bootloader, bootable-media

I bought a new SSD for my laptop. It is SATA3 compatible with SATA2, but the BIOS doesn't recognize it. On the other hand, if I boot a Linux live CD I can access the contents of the SSD, so I can be sure that the problem is only on the BIOS and not on the SSD itself.

Would it be possible to prepare a flash drive with the minimum data to start booting Windows, but store all the Windows files on the SSD?

Comment: What do you mean that the BIOS doesn't recognize it? I don't think you could see it with Linux if the BIOS can't see it.

Comment: If its a new SSD how does it already contain data?

Comment: @fooot and Ramhound. Yes, the BIOS doesn't detect the SSD but the OS can. That's not something unusual. At the end, the BIOS is just a program but is used in the initial stages of the OS loading, but the OS doesn't need the BIOS to access the hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound the SSD contains data because I could boot the recovery CD and load the image of the OS.

Comment: How did you determine the BIOS can't see the drive because thats not actually normal.